# Odoo not loading in local syatem

Tags: odoo-8

I have installed oddo 8.0 in my system.
After I login into odoo the center frame is not loading completely.
I searched every setting in odoo but did not find anything.
I wanted to attach screen shot but as I am new here I dont have reqd reputations to attach images.
If anybody has come across such problem, please suggest how to solve.
Thanks.

Comment: Check if this url works, replacing the host and port `host:port/web#page=0&limit=80&view_type=list&model=res.users&action=76`

Comment: @Sunil Does it possible to write your each and every stpes you should followed from your side.?

Comment: @ChesuCR that URL didnt help

Comment: Maybe it is a cache or cookies problem. Try to open Odoo in a incognito window

Comment: @ChesuCR thanks for the reply, that URL didnt help, still center frame is not loading completely

Comment: @DaSaDiYa ChaiTAnYa  Hi, I downloaded odoo_8.0.latest exe file, installed it on my system (windows 7 32bit) thats it, got the URL http://localhost:8069/  there created database and logged into it. Expect for that frame everything is fine